# What to do landing in Goa at 3:30 am?

Tags: india, goa-india

I am landing in Goa at 3:30 am. I need to be in Agonda beach by the end of the afternoon.

Since there are no buses at that time, my only option would be to take a taxi to Agonda beach. But that sounds a bit boring and maybe there is something interesting to see or do near the airport before travelling south by bus?

I think I'd need to take a bus to Margao and then Agonda or something like this.

Comment: I would take a nap...

Comment: Would be a good idea except I have a 10 hour flight to get there so I'll be all napped out.